# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. In my MERN todo app using Vite Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, vite

I am trying to make a MERN ToDo list app, my folder structure is : 1 main folder in which I have api (Backend) and client (Frontend) folder.
In api: server.js & models folder, in which I have todo.js, mongo schema.
In client: regular Vite react app structure.

I am expecting to perform the crud operations on my todolist...
I tried to debug but can't figure it out... I took a long break from development due to exams!
here's my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const API_BASE = "http://localhost:3001";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [newTodo, setNewTodos] = useState("");
  const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  }, []);

  const getTodos = () => {
    fetch(API_BASE + "/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setTodos(data))
      .catch((err) => console.error("Error: ", err));
  };

  const completeTodo = async (id) => {
    const data = await fetch(API_BASE + "/todo/complete" + id).then((res) =>
      res.json()
    );

    setTodos((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === data._id) {
          todo.complete = data.complete;
        }
        return todo;
      })
    );
  };

  const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
    const data = await fetch(API_BASE + "todo.delete/" + id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    setTodos((todos) => todos.filter(todo._id !== data._id));
  };

  const addTodo = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(API_BASE + "/todo/new", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text: newTodo,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    setTodos([...todos, data]);
    setPopupActive(false);
    setNewTodos("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <h1>Welcome, mj...</h1>
        <h4>Your Tasks...</h4>
        <div className="todos">
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <div
              className={"todo " + (todo.complete ? "is-complete" : "")}
              key={todo._id}
              onClick={completeTodo(todo._id)}
            >
              <div className="checkbox"></div>

              <div className="text">{todo.text}</div>

              <div className="delete-todo" onClick={deleteTodo(todo._id)}>
                x
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="addPopup" onClick={setPopupActive(true)}>
          +
        </div>
        {popupActive ? (
          <div className="popup">
            <div className="closePopup" onClick={setPopupActive(false)}>
              X
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <h3> Add todo...</h3>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="add-todo-input"
                onChange={(e) => setNewTodo(e.target.value)}
                value={newTodo}
              />
              <div className="button" onClick={addTodo}>
                Create Task...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I did use fat arrow functions before this, but the error persisted!!

Comment: [Here's the codesandbox of the whole project...](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mjshubham21/clg-api-project/main?workspaceId=fe256bc6-8c9b-4e90-91aa-223661878145&file=%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx)

Comment: above had a spelling error setNewTodo, I fixed the spelling in my local but didn't do anything...

Answer (score 1):

You are using setState inside a useEffect hook, which makes an infinite loop.

if you're updating your state in an effect, you must add a condition for the function to run or you'll create an infinite loop.

anytime your state updated, it makes the page rerender, so if you don't put a condition for it - it will re-render the dom and the effect will start running again and it will update your state again which will cause an infinite loop.

here's an example:

```js
const Example = () => {
  
  const [state,setState] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFakeData = () => {
      if (state.length < 1) {
        fetch("https://fakeData.com")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setState({ data });
          });
      }
    };

    fetchFakeData();
  }, []);
  
  
  return <></>

}
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/simple-example-4yms0q?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx)

Comment: I looked into my server.js and had to fix my routes, It works now... re-render errors are gone...